# Why does .loc assignment with two sets of brackets result in NaN in a pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, series

I have a DataFrame:

|  | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Paul | 25 |
| 1 | John | 27 |
| 2 | Bill | 23 |

I know that if I enter:

> ```
> df[['name']] = df[['age']]
> ```

I'll get the following:

|  | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 25 | 25 |
| 1 | 27 | 27 |
| 2 | 23 | 23 |

But I expect the **same** result from the command:

> ```
> df.loc[:, ['name']] = df.loc[:, ['age']]
> ```

But instead, I get this:

|  | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | **NaN** | 25 |
| 1 | **NaN** | 27 |
| 2 | **NaN** | 23 |

For some reason, if I omit those square brackets `[]` around column names, I'll get exactly what I expected. That is the command:

> ```
> df.loc[:, 'name'] = df.loc[:, 'age']
> ```

gives the right result:

|  | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 25 | 25 |
| 1 | 27 | 27 |
| 2 | 23 | 23 |

**Why does two pairs of brackets with `.loc` result in NaN?** Is it some sort of a bug or is it intended behaviour? I can't figure out the reason for such a behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because for the `loc` assignment all index axes are aligned, including the columns: Since `age` and `name` do not match, there is no data to assign, hence the NaNs.

You can make it work by renaming the columns:

```
df.loc[:, ["name"]] = df.loc[:, ["age"]].rename(columns={"age": "name"})
```

or by accessing the numpy array:

```
df.loc[:, ["name"]] = df.loc[:, ["age"]].values
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But why do column indexes need to match? I can see why one want row indexes to match, but why column indexes?

Comment: I can see how that might be convenient for larger tables. In any case, you still have other options to assign without column alignments, so that's not a constraint.

Comment: Could you give a little example of how that might be convenient for larger tables?

Answer (score 12):

You can find this Warning about data alignment in the docs under [Indexing and selecting data § Basics](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#basics) (emphasis mine):

> pandas **aligns all AXES** when setting `Series` and `DataFrame` from **`.loc`**.
>
> This will **not** modify `df` because the column **alignment is before value assignment.**
>
> ```
> In [9]: df[['A', 'B']]
> Out[9]: 
>                    A         B
> 2000-01-01 -0.282863  0.469112
> 2000-01-02 -0.173215  1.212112
> 2000-01-03 -2.104569 -0.861849
> 2000-01-04 -0.706771  0.721555
> 2000-01-05  0.567020 -0.424972
> 2000-01-06  0.113648 -0.673690
> 2000-01-07  0.577046  0.404705
> 2000-01-08 -1.157892 -0.370647
>
> In [10]: df.loc[:, ['B', 'A']] = df[['A', 'B']]
>
> In [11]: df[['A', 'B']]
> Out[11]: 
>                    A         B
> 2000-01-01 -0.282863  0.469112
> 2000-01-02 -0.173215  1.212112
> 2000-01-03 -2.104569 -0.861849
> 2000-01-04 -0.706771  0.721555
> 2000-01-05  0.567020 -0.424972
> 2000-01-06  0.113648 -0.673690
> 2000-01-07  0.577046  0.404705
> 2000-01-08 -1.157892 -0.370647
> ```

#### To Explicitly Avoid Automatic Alignment

> Accessing the array can be useful when you need to do some operation without the index (to disable automatic alignment, for example).

The alignment comes into play when LHS and RHS are dataframes. To avoid alignment try using.

```
df.loc[:, ['B', 'A']] = df[['A', 'B']].to_numpy()
```

---

You have two cases at hand,

- `.loc` assignment with `pd.DataFrame`.
- `.loc` assignment with `pd.Series` in EDIT.

### `.loc` assignment in `pd.DataFrame`

In `pd.DataFrame` has 2 axes `index` and `columns`. So, when you do

> ```
> df.loc[:, ['name']] = df.loc[:, ['age']]
> ```

LHS has column `A` which doesn't align with RHS column `B` hence resulting in all `NaN` after assignment.

- From docs [Data alignment and arithmetic](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#data-alignment-and-arithmetic) (emphasis mine)

  > Data alignment between DataFrame objects automatically **align on both the columns and the index (row labels)**. Again, the resulting object will have the union of the column and row labels.

  You can find this behaviour in most of the pandas' operations if not all. Example, addition, subtraction, multiplication etc. Non matching indices and columns are filled with `NaN`.

  Example from **Data alignment and arithmetic**

  > ```
  > df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
  > df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(7, 3), columns=["A", "B", "C"])
  >
  > df + df2 
  >
  >          A         B         C   D
  > 0  0.045691 -0.014138  1.380871 NaN
  > 1 -0.955398 -1.501007  0.037181 NaN
  > 2 -0.662690  1.534833 -0.859691 NaN
  > 3 -2.452949  1.237274 -0.133712 NaN
  > 4  1.414490  1.951676 -2.320422 NaN
  > 5 -0.494922 -1.649727 -1.084601 NaN
  > 6 -1.047551 -0.748572 -0.805479 NaN
  > 7       NaN       NaN       NaN NaN
  > 8       NaN       NaN       NaN NaN
  > 9       NaN       NaN       NaN NaN
  > ```

To answer your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69954697/weird-behaviour-of-assignment-in-pandas-dataframe#comment123659697_69954848)

> But why do column indexes need to match? I can see why one want row indexes to match, but why column indexes?

Let's take a look at the above example, if columns are not aligned how would you add two DataFrames? It makes sense to align them on columns and indices.

---

### `.loc` assignment in `pd.Series`

`pd.Series` has only **one** axis i.e `index`. That is the reason why it worked when you did

> ```
> df.loc[:, 'name'] = df.loc[:, 'age']
> ```

As `pd.Series` has only one axis, pandas tried to align `index` and it worked. Of course, if `index` doesn't align it results in `NaN` values.

From docs [Vectorized operations and label alignment with Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#vectorized-operations-and-label-alignment-with-series) (emphasis mine):

> The result of an **operation between unaligned Series** will have the union of the indexes involved. If a **label is not found** in one Series or the other, the **result will be marked as missing `NaN`**.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! But could you clarify, why it's not the case for ```df[['name']] = df[['age']]```? I mean both ```df[['name']]``` and ```df[['age']]``` return ```pd.DataFrame``` object. But the result of this assignment is correct (without ```NaN```s). Why there is no longer alignment in this case?

Comment: @mathgeek Alignment only kicks in when setting/assigning with `.loc` and `.iloc`.

Comment: @mathgeek You can verify this using `df[['A', 'B']] = df[['B', 'A']]` would swap the columns but when used with `.loc` i.e `df.loc[:, ['B', 'A']] = df[['A', 'B']]` they don't swap `

Answer (score 1):

When you use double brackets [[]] you are assigning a DataFrame. What you want is assign a (column) Series, and for that you use only one bracket [].

Here is some code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Paul','John','Bill'], 'age':[25,27,23]})
print('Inital Dataframe:\n',df)

df[['name']] = df[['age']]
print("\ndf[['name']] = df[['age']]\n",df)

print("df.loc[:, ['age']]:", type(df.loc[:, ['age']]))
print("df.loc[:, ['name']]:", type(df.loc[:, ['name']]))
df.loc[:, ['name']] = df.loc[:, ['age']]
print("\ndf.loc[:, ['name']] = df.loc[:, ['age']]\n",df)
    
print('=======================')
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Paul','John','Bill'], 'age':[25,27,23]})
print('Inital Dataframe:\n',df)

print("type(df.loc[:, 'age']):", type(df.loc[:, 'age']))
print("type(df.loc[:, 'name']):", type(df.loc[:, 'name']))
df.loc[:, 'name'] = df.loc[:, 'age']
print("\ndf.loc[:, 'name'] = df.loc[:, 'age']\n",df)
```

And the output:

```
Inital Dataframe:
    name  age
0  Paul   25
1  John   27
2  Bill   23

df[['name']] = df[['age']]
    name  age
0    25   25
1    27   27
2    23   23
df.loc[:, ['age']]: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
df.loc[:, ['name']]: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

df.loc[:, ['name']] = df.loc[:, ['age']]
    name   age
0   NaN  25.0
1   NaN  27.0
2   NaN  23.0
=======================
Inital Dataframe:
    name  age
0  Paul   25
1  John   27
2  Bill   23
type(df.loc[:, 'age']): <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
type(df.loc[:, 'name']): <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

df.loc[:, 'name'] = df.loc[:, 'age']
    name  age
0    25   25
1    27   27
2    23   23
```

However, here is another strange behaviour: Assigning the double brackets to difference variables, say `df1` and `df2`, and then `df1 = df2` works!
Here is some more code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Paul','John','Bill'], 'age':[25,27,23]})
print('Inital Dataframe:\n',df)

df1 = df.loc[:, ['name']]
df2 = df.loc[:, ['age']]
print("\ndf1 = df.loc[:, ['name']]\n",df1)
print("\ndf2 = df.loc[:, ['age']]\n",df2)

df1=df2
print("\ndf1=df2\ndf1:\n",df1)
```

And the output:

```
Inital Dataframe:
    name  age
0  Paul   25
1  John   27
2  Bill   23

df1 = df.loc[:, ['name']]
    name
0  Paul
1  John
2  Bill

df2 = df.loc[:, ['age']]
    age
0   25
1   27
2   23

df1=df2
df1:
    age
0   25
1   27
2   23
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I asked about the behavior of double brackets, since that was my issue. I just used only one column name to simplify the example.